# Code jumps to another module for no reason

Tags: excel, vba, module

I've got the following VBA code in a sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Call GenerateRCSection.ClearPreviousData

End Sub
```

Which calls the following VBA module code:

```
Public Sub ClearPreviousData()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Graphs")

    'Clear previous data
    ws.Range("K48:L49").Clear
    ws.Range("Q48:R49").Clear
    ws.Range("K52:L100").Clear
    ws.Range("Q52:R100").Clear


End Sub
```

Everything seems ok, but when I run the code, Excel call me other modules in line         `ws.Range("K48:L49").Clear`...
I dont understand why and it takes minutes to run the other modules (they have a large code inside)..

Can someone help me understand?
Does it have anything to do with the book and sheet references?

Best regards

Comment: I guess those _"other modules"_ are some sheet `Change()` events handler. Should that be the case you could place an `Application.EnableEvents=False` right before `ws.Range("K48:L49").Clear` and `Application.EnableEvents=False` right before `End Sub`, unless those `Change()` event handelers are actually needed

Comment: How do I know if they are sheet Change()?

Comment: Based on your help, I'm trying to find something that is triggering other modules, but no luck so far..

Comment: Usually I declare modules Subs as public? Should they be private?

Comment: Right-click the sheet tab, view code and see if anything is there. If not try ThisWorkbook module. If you step through your code you'll see what's going on.

Comment: In ´ThisWorkbook´ I had this code:

'Public Sub Workbook_Open()
'
'    ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = True   'This causes Excel to always recalculate all formulas, regardless of whether it believes recalculation is required. This setting remains in effect until Excel is restarted.
'    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
'
'End Sub

But now it is commented and I've restarted excel.. This may be the cause right?

Comment: That alone cannot be the cause. Follow SJR suggestions to find out all possible (called) sheets event handlers

Comment: I've already searched for it but no luck.. I'm running VBA code step by step (F8) but I cannot find it..

Comment: well, if you run the code step by step (pressing F8) and once it executes `ws.Range("K48:L49").Clear` it _really_ doesn't jump anywhere else and only takes minutes for the next step, then I have two supects: 1) change `Clear` to `ClearContents` 2) you have extensive conditional formatting in place

Comment: Many thanks for the tip!!! :) I noticed that, everything I write something in a cell that does not play any role, Excel takes 2-3 seconds to acept.. It looks like it is recalculating everything!! Maybe this is what is happening... How to stop it?

Comment: I've disabled the Formulas->Calculations->Manual and the code does not jumo anymore :) However, I dont think it is good because I have to recalculate all formulas by "hand" right? How can I overcome this?

Comment: Use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of the macro and  `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` by its end